# multiprocessing.Queue - Will a single thread hang on `queue.get()` if not `queue.empty()` is called before `queue.get()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) has this to say about `multiprocessing.Queue().empty()`:

> Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.

Assume I have **a single thread/process** that calls queue.get(), as opposed to multiple consumers.

Is it possible for the following code to hang at `queue.get()`?

```
def process_queue(queue):
    while not queue.empty():
        item = queue.get()
        print(f"The item is {item}")
```

I would think that so long as you have a single thread/process calling `process_queue`, the code will never hang.

Of course, as soon as multiple threads/processes are calling `process_queue`, all bets are off.

Comment: I agree with your logical deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only a single consumer, you are correct, that code will never block on `queue.get()`.

Note that your code block above would not work as expected if it happened to start running before any of your producers were able to start populating the queue, or if it happened to exhaust the queue while the producer(s) still had more items to add. That might not be relevant for your use-case, but if it is, you may want to use a sentinel/poison pill to tell your consumer when it should stop checking for new items, instead. That way it would only block on `get()` in cases where the producer isn't done producing new items.